# data from local storage is not appended and replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Objects are being saved into localstorage and I want to retrieve that object and append to the page, also I want to change key name everytime new form is submitted, so at first key = key and then on next form submit I want key = key1 etc.

However I do not know how to achieve that, can someone help me?

```
var existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key")) || [];
$('body').append(existingData);
$('form').submit(function() {
var newArray = [];
    $(".add_id2").each(function(){
    newArray.push($(this).val());
});
var newArray2 = [];
    $(".add_id").each(function(){
    newArray2.push($(this).val());
});

var newData = {
  'title': $("#title").val(),
  'ingredients': $("#ingredients").val(),
  'instructions': $("#inst").val(),
  'moreingredients': newArray,
  'moreinstruction': newArray2,
  'img': img,
    };
existingData.push(newData);
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(existingData));
```

Comment: Hi @Przemek,
Please create a codepen demo, so I can check what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: What is wrong with your existing code, how is it failing?

Comment: Basically if you submit the form once it saves the values to the localstorage however if I input form again with new values, old values are there but not the new ones

Answer (score 0):

You can make the constructor function and call that with the new keyword...Please have a look at this. Hope this will help you.

**Example:-**

```
function formData(title, ingredients, instructions, moreingredients, img) {
    this.title = title;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.moreingredients = moreingredients;
    this.img = img;
}


var newData = new formData($("#title").val(), $("#ingredients").val(), $("#inst").val(), newArray, newArray2);
```